# XSLT transformation doesn't work with XALAN

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm using [Apache Xalan](http://xalan.apache.org/) 2.7.1 to do an XSLT transformation.

I'm trying to transform following `input` to `expected-output`.

**input**

```
<customer>
  <customer-name>Diecast Collectables</customer-name>
  <phone xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
  <city>Boston</city>
</customer>
```

**xslt**

```
  <xsl:template match="node()[@xsi:nil = 'true']">
     <xsl:copy>NULL</xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

**expected-output** (Note the 'NULL' value)

```
<customer>
   <customer-name>Diecast Collectables</customer-name>
   <phone xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">NULL</phone>
   <city>Boston</city>
</customer>
```

**But this is the output I get with Xalan java library.** (Note there's no 'NULL' value)

```
<customer>
    <customer-name>Diecast Collectables</customer-name>
    <phone xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"></phone>
    <city>Boston</city>
</customer>
```

But surprisingly, above XSLT gives expected output in [this online tool](http://www.freeformatter.com/xsl-transformer.html).

Can someone please explain what's the reason for this difference?

Thanks,
Bhathiya

[EDIT]

**Transfromation Code**

```
public void transform() throws Exception {
    OMElement omElemHeader = AXIOMUtil.stringToOM("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?>\n" +
            "         <customer>\n" +
            "            <customer-name>Diecast Collectables</customer-name>\n" +
            "            <contact-last-name>Franco</contact-last-name>\n" +
            "            <phone xsi:nil=\"true\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"/>\n" +
            "            <city>Boston</city>\n" +
            "         </customer>\n");

    TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    File xslt = new File("/data/xslt.xslt");
    Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(
            new StreamSource(new FileInputStream(xslt)));


    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    Source xmlSource = new OMSource(omElemHeader);
    transformer.transform(xmlSource, new StreamResult(outputStream));
    ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(outputStream.toByteArray());
    XMLStreamReader reader2 = XMLInputFactory.newInstance().
            createXMLStreamReader(inputStream);
    StAXOMBuilder builder2 = new StAXOMBuilder(reader2);
    OMElement out = builder2.getDocumentElement();
    System.out.println(out);
}
```

Comment: Have a look a this (http://xsltransform.net/nbUY4kv/1). It uses Xalan 2.7.1. It outputs okay.

Comment: Joel, this link does not work.

Comment: it seems that the website is down.

Comment: Try the version of Xalan from Apache. The version bundled with the Oracle JDK is buggy, and no-one seems interested in fixing the bugs.

Comment: I got it from apache one.
http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/xalan/xalan-j

Comment: I have tried http://xsltransform.net/nbUY4kv/1 now and it is accessible and working fine.

Comment: Hmm.. I added transformation code to the question. Can someone please verify it is correct? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. There was a typo in `xsi` namespace in xslt. (I should have posted the complete xslt in the question. :-/ )

Anyway, Thanks all who tried to help me.